# Matlab plotting, Constant / variable

Tags: matlab, graph

```
x = -5:5;
f= 2/x;
plot(f,x)
```

Basically this gives me this error:

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Obligatorisk2 (line 16)
    f= 2/x;

Error in run (line 63)
evalin('caller', [script ';']);
```

Guessing I'm overlooking something very simple, or just got the wrong idea about how to do this :) Would love some help!

Comment: Indeed very simple. It should be `f=2./x`, to divide each element of x. Also, I suppose you'll want `plot(x,f)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`./`** for element-wise division.

```
x = -5:5;
f= 2./x;
plot(f,x)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should also use plot(x,y) as suggested by MATLAB documentation instead of plot(y,x).

Therefore we have:

```
x = -5:5;
f= 2./x;
plot(x,f)
```